# Execute second command in chain as different user

Tags: shell, sudo

When we are logged in as `user1` and run:

`$ sudo su user2 && cd && ./script.sh status`

It will execute both `cd` and `./script.sh status` in context of `user1`.

**How to write above command so** `cd` **executes as** `user2`**?** (In this case, go to ~ folder of `user2`, not `user1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following commands to run as another user or as root user

`sudo su - user2 -c "cd && ./script.sh status"`

Comment: @ilkkachu: the `-c` option to `sudo` does not do what you think.

Comment: @enzotib, ah, sorry, you'd need to do `sudo -u user2 sh -c "..."`. My main point was that `sudo` and `su` are both used to raise privileges, there's not much point in using both. (Unless you're allowed to use `sudo` to run anything as root, but not as any other user.)